# Spring boot upload file to S3 too slow when run on EC2 instance

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm using aws-java-sdk(version 1.11.874) in my spring boot application in order to upload file to S3.

Everything working great when run on my local machine, it take a few milisecon to upload file 75kb.

But when I deploy my application to EC2 (t2.small) with the same config aws account, application got over 10 minutes to upload file only 75kb.

My upload function is below:

```
public String uploadFile(String keyName, InputStream inputStream, String type) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    String newFileName = String.format("%s.%s", Utils.generateRandomString("i"), FilenameUtils.getExtension(keyName) == null ? "" : FilenameUtils.getExtension(keyName));
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("avatar")) {
        newFileName = avatarFolder + "avatar/" + newFileName;
    } else {
        newFileName = avatarFolder + newFileName;
    }
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, newFileName, inputStream, new ObjectMetadata())
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
    Upload upload = transferManager.upload(request);
    try {
        upload.waitForCompletion();
        return String.format("https://%s.s3-%s.amazonaws.com/%s", bucket, region, newFileName);
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
        log.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Can anybody suggest me any solution? thanks.